# Centos 7 shows an error message

Tags: centos

Every time i boot my machine I get this error showing and I've no idea what this is and how to fix it?

WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 20 at drivers/input/input-leds.c:115 input_leds_connect+0x276/0x280

Can anybody share their expertise on how to resolve it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can anybody share their expertise on how to resolve it please?

> WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 20 at drivers/input/input-leds.c:115 input_leds_connect+0x276/0x280

This has been reported to redhat and they are working to resolve the problem:

> **Issue**
>
> After plugging the device that declares more LEDs than it is known to
>   the input-leds driver, the following warning may appear: Raw
>
> kernel: WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 32742 at drivers/input/input-leds.c:115
>   input_leds_connect+0x276/0x280

[image]

Source [Plugging devices that declare more LEDs than it is known to to input-leds causes kernel warnings and soft lockups](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3521341)